# Random Sub Domains being generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain, wordpress, subdomain, url

I'm having a strange issues where a coworker of mine received a google alert about 'Deeper Learning' content -- this normally directs her to any new happenings on her keyword'Deeper Learning'

This alert directed here to our site "DeeperLearning4All.org" but it had the url **odfoallocneujjt.deeperlearning4all.org/** which looks like a sub domain. I didn't create this subdomain nor can I find it anywhere on our domain host page (Network Solutions).  This is Wordpress site on an AWS server. I'm concerned about the security of our site.

If I am in the wrong stack, please let me know the best place to direct this question.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a wildcard record setup and all queries that don't go to otherwise registered names go to  34.196.48.109 (which is the same as `deeperlearning4all.org`) . In itself, this is not a security issue per se.

Comment: Ah thank you for your quick reply. That's bizarre. Is there something I can do to prevent this wildcard?  Is there a reason people would want to use wildcard records?

Comment: If you don't need this wildcard record (you problably don't), you can safely delete it in the management interface of your domain registrar. Look up their docs to learn how this is done.

Comment: You rock Sven. Thank you. I'll look into that now.